# My properties are always default values in MVVM model

Tags: android, mvvm, xamarin, mvvmcross

I've got MvvmCross Xamarin Android project and I would like to ask about some strange behaviour of my button.

When I open my view with button - button appear and it's visible. Then from time to time my property MyEnumCurrentId is changing - always to MyEnum.OK. However when I put break on setter I saw that property before on MyEnumCurrentId wasn't last one (MyEnum.OK) but it's always 0.

So I put counter to check if my model remember my properties that was set before. What I notice is that my counter is always -1, even when counter++ execute few times.

In app my button disappear from time to time and that's the problem. I think it's because RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyEnumCurrentId is always executing, because my properties don't know their value that was set before.

So my question is why that happen? Should I move those properties to view model and that should fix problem, or?

When other activity change current MyEnumCurrentId I am setting

## Model

```
     private int counter = -1;

     public MyEnum MyEnumCurrentId
        {
            get { return _MyEnumCurrentId; }
            set
            {
                if (counter <2)
                {
                    counter++;
                    if(value == MyEnum.OK)
                        _IsMyTextVisible = true;
                    else
                        _IsMyTextVisible = false;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsMyTextVisible);
                }
                _MyEnumCurrentId = value;      

                RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyEnumCurrentId);            
            }
        }


    private bool _IsMyTextVisible;

    public bool IsMyTextVisible
    {
        get{ return _IsMyTextVisible; }
        set
        {
            _logger.Info("changing property on IsMyTextVisible: "+value);
            _IsMyTextVisible = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsMyTextVisible);
        }
    }
```

## XML

```
<Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                local:MvxBind="Text MyText; Visible IsMyTextVisible; Typeface StringToFont('MyFont')" />
```

Comment: I'm not really seeing the purpose of the _counter_. First of all, when you have data bound properties, you code should use the property getters/setters instead of the backing variables. In other words, you should use `IsMyTextVisible = true;`. Secondly, what is responsible for setting the initial value of _MyEnumCurrentId_? Also, does this value need to persist across activations?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how it works in Xamarin Android  but  i think issue is Your assigning **bool** property which has result **true** or **false**  (in view model)
and in view your assigning that bool value to **visibility** property but visibility value can set to only Invisible or Visible not true or false i hope you get it